# Suming up dynamic table last column javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Please someone should help out on this, everything seems to be working fine but the sumQTY() function is where am having problem with, its iterating through the row cells but just not identifing the input box. Thanks
Bellow is the script.'
How do i get the sumQTY() to work well.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(dataTable) {
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if (rowCount < 4) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
    row.id = 'row_'+rowCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].outerHTML;            
    }
    var listitems= row.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
        listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
    }
} else {
        alert("Maximum Row Reached.");
}
}
function deleteRow(dataTable) {
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 2) { // limit the user from removing all the fields
            alert("Cannot Remove all the Rows.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}
}
function calculate(elementID) {
var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[id=item')[0].value;
var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[id=price')[0].value;
var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[id=qty')[0];
var myResult1 = myBox1 * (parseFloat(myBox2)) ;
var mresult = myResult1.toFixed(2);                          
total.value = mresult;
}
function sumQty(dataTable) {
var total = 0;
var confirm = 10;
var colCount;
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    colCount = row.cells.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
        var node = row.cells[j].childNodes[0];
        if (node.name == "qty[]") {
            total += parseInt(node.value);
            confirm = confirm + 1;
        }else{confirm = confirm - 1;}
    }
}
 //alert("total = " + total + " " + rowCount + " " + colCount + " " + confirm);
//document.getElementById("mee").innerHTML = "Sum Value = " + total;
//console.log(sumVal);
return total;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

Bellow is the html table code

```
<form action="" method="post" name="f">  

<table id="dataTable" class="form">
<thead>
    <th style="width:20px"></th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Description</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Item Units</th>
<th>Total Price (#)</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id='row_0'>
            <td><input style="width:20px" type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" /></td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="ite[]" onChange="search('row_1')" id="ite" placeholder="Item">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="price[]" id="des" placeholder="Description">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="item[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" onchange="sumQty()" id="item" placeholder="unit price">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="price[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" id="price" placeholder="units">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="qty[]" id="qty" placeholder="total price">
            </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<span id="mee"></span>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="submit" value="Insert" name="submit" />
<input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="sumtotal" placeholder="total price"/>
</form>
```

I want to output the total sum of the last col in the input field with name="sumtotal".

Thanks.

Comment: What you want from the function?

Comment: Can you also provide an example HTML?

Comment: ok, will do that right away

Comment: @AnandG, i want the last function to compute the total of the last columns and output it in a seperate input textBox

Comment: I recommend that you use a javascript library like JQuery to easily manipulate and select DOM elements and you should format your code for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to work a bit more on when the sumQTy is being called, since when it gets called the row price = NaN since there is no given a quantity, you can overwrite that behavior by making a small change in the calculate function or having a starter value o "1" in the qty.

This are the changes I made it to have it working:

In your HTML
`<input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="price[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" id="price" placeholder="units" value="1">`

In calculate function

```
 var multiplier = Number(myBox2) || 1;
 var myResult1 = myBox1 * multiplier;
```

Better implementation of sumQty

```
 function sumQty(dataTable) {
 var confirm = 10;
  var colCount;
  var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
  let rows = [...table.querySelectorAll('[name*=qty]')];

  let total = rows.reduce((prev, current)=>{
    let to_be_added = Number(current.value) || 0;
    return prev + to_be_added;
  },0)

  return total;
}
```

Comment: I love you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhh! @nicolas-m-pardo. Have been trying to get this done for quite a while now and haven't been able to go past it. Am going to sleep like a baby tonight, thanks to you. One Love...

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, you can up vote and mark it as the right answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function addRow(dataTable) {
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if (rowCount < 4) { // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[1].cells.length;
    row.id = 'row_'+rowCount;
    for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.outerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].outerHTML;            
    }
    var listitems= row.getElementsByTagName("input")
    for (i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
        listitems[i].setAttribute("oninput", "calculate('"+row.id+"')");
    }
} else {
        alert("Maximum Row Reached.");
}
}
function deleteRow(dataTable) {
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
    if (null !== chkbox && true === chkbox.checked) {
        if (rowCount <= 2) { // limit the user from removing all the fields
            alert("Cannot Remove all the Rows.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}
}
function calculate(elementID) {
var mainRow = document.getElementById(elementID);
var myBox1 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[id=item')[0].value;
var myBox2 = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[id=price')[0].value;
var total = mainRow.querySelectorAll('[id=qty')[0];
var multiplier = Number(myBox2) || 1;
var myResult1 = myBox1 * multiplier;
//var myResult1 = myBox1 * (parseFloat(myBox2)) ;
var mresult = myResult1.toFixed(2);                          
total.value = mresult;
//function sumQty(dataTable) {
var confirm = 10;
var colCount;
var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
let rows = [...table.querySelectorAll('[name*=qty]')];
let total2 = rows.reduce((prev, current)=>{
    let to_be_added = Number(current.value) || 0;
    return prev + to_be_added;
},0)
console.log(total2);
$("#sumtotal").val(total2.toFixed(2));
return total2;
}
function amountDue() {
var amount =  parseFloat($("#sumtotal").val());
var paidd =   parseFloat($("#paid").val());
var balance =  amount - paidd;
$("#due").val(balance.toFixed(2));
$("#due2").val(balance.toFixed(2));
}
```

html code!

```
<form action="" method="post">
<article>
<div>
    <address>
            <p>Customer ID=<br>Staff ID= <?php echo $_SESSION['staffid']?></p>
        </address>
        <table class="meta">
            <tr>
                <th><span>invoice #</span></th>
                <td><input type="text" name="ind"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><span>Amount Due</span></th>
                <td><input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="" id="due2" placeholder="#" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: white" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
</article>
<article>
<table id="dataTable" class="form">
<thead>
<th style="width:20px"></th>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Unit Price</th>
<th>Item Units</th>
<th>Sub Total (#)</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr id='row_0'>
        <td><input style="width:20px" type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" /></td>
        <td>
                <select required="required" name="" onChange="" id="" placeholder="Item">
                    <option value="0"> select an item</option>
                    <option value="1"></option>
                    <option value="2"></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="" id="" placeholder="Description">
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" name="item[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" id="item" placeholder="unit price">
        </td>
    <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="price[]" oninput="calculate('row_0')" id="price" placeholder="units" value="1">
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="qty[]" id="qty" placeholder="sub total" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: white">
        </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<span id="mee"></span>
            <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" class="butto" />
<input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" class="butto"/>

<table class="balance" id="datatable2">
        <tr>
            <th><span>Total</span></th>
            <td><input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="tot" id="sumtotal" placeholder="total price" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: white"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th><span>Amount Paid</span></th>
            <td><input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="" id="paid" placeholder="#" oninput="amountDue()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th><span>Balance Due</span></th>
            <td><input type="text" required="required" class="small" name="" id="due" placeholder="#" readonly="readonly" style="background-color: white"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </article>
    <aside><center>
        <h1><span>Additional Notes</span></h1>
        </center>
        <div contenteditable>
            <p>Enter additional info here</p>
        </div>
    </aside>            
</ul>

     <ul id="core" class="hide" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto;">
                 </ul>

             <ul id="jquerytuts" class="hide" style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:auto;">

             </ul>

             <ul id="classics" class="hide">

             </ul>

         </div> <!-- END List Wrap -->
                <center>
                <div class="input-container">
                <INPUT type="submit" value="Insert" name="submit" class="butto" style="width:100%"/>
            </div>

            </form>
```